# How to extract "string" property names from an interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, conditional-types

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHkCyBRA+ugIQClsBhAFWQG8AoZe5MYMAGwgC4GGBnMKUAOYAaOgxZwARhBacuyXvxDDR9bgHsAthAJq1MhhN1s4IEV3VaAInEizk1yGZ6aIAOQCuGqVE4hP3mgBfGhowAE8ABxQAaWwATVRkAF5kAGsIMLUYNCw8QhIKAG4Q8KjkbAAPPkQwVD5BAB5yAD5ktIys5EoIKogQABNueXqlZAB+dszsyl8IADdoYtKUVHIAJQBJVwBxXFiEtsrqhFqRgQaMHHxiMhagA)

I want to extract the `string` properties from `SOME_OBJECT` and get it as a union type. Therefore, in the example below, I expect `STRING_KEYS` to be of type  `"title" | "label"`

```
interface SOME_OBJECT {
    title:      string,
    label:      string,
    someBool:   boolean,
    someDate:   Date,
    someNumber: number
}

type ExtractString<T> = keyof T extends string ? keyof T : never;

type STRING_KEYS = ExtractString<SOME_OBJECT>  // <----- THIS SHOULD BE "title" | "label"
```

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

I think I'm in the right direction here (by using conditional types), but I'm not quiet there yet. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got the idea from the example below from [Typescript Docs: Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

[image]

So I've adapted it, and it works:

```
interface SOME_OBJECT {
    title:      string,
    label:      string,
    someBool:   boolean,
    someDate:   Date,
    someNumber: number
}

type ExtractStringPropertyNames<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never
}[keyof T]

type STRING_KEYS = ExtractStringPropertyNames<SOME_OBJECT>
```

[image]

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHkCyBRA+ugIQClsBhAFWQG8AoZe5MYMAGwgC4GGBnMKUAOYAaOgxZwARhBacuyXvxDDR9bgHsAthAJq1MhhN1s4IEV3VaAInEizk1yGZ6aIAOQCuGqVE4hP3mgBfGhowAE8ABxQAaWwATVRkAF5kAGsIMLUYNCw8QhIKAG4Q8KjkbAAPPkQwVD5BAAUoNSiocNc4LW4AHnIAPmTqFWQAbWjkUDSMrORyAF1OcjG55AgqiBAAE255eqVkAH5kcd8IADdoIJH0zOz5ksiUVHIAJQBJVwBxXFiEwcrqghansBE0WtB2p0ID0MDh8MQyP0aEA)

If possible, I'm still interested in see other ways of doing that. Especially if there are more straightforward ways of doing it, as I think this answer feels like a "hack", 'cause it does not make it very clear what the code is doing.

---

**UPDATE (HOW IT WORKS)**

I've studied a bit more to understand what the code is actually doing, and I think I've figured it out.

I've broken it into two steps:

**STEP 1**

In the first step, a new object/type will be created.

The keys for this new object will the same keys `K in keyof T` as from the keys of the generic type `T` (`SOME_OBJECT` in the example).

And for the values of those keys, we'll check in the generic type `T`, if the values for those properties `K` extends `string`. Which means that those values are assignable to `string`. For example: `string`, `"some_hard_coded_string_type"` and `any` will all pass the test.

For each property that passes the test, we will repeat its key `K` name as the value for them, otherwise will pass `never`. You can see the result in `STEP_1_RESULT` below.

[image]

**STEP 2**

In this step, we'll simply get that object generated from the **step 1**, and ask
Typescript to return all of its possible values, by doing `type STEP_2<T> = T[keyof T]`.

Remember that `keyof T` represents the union of all properties from `T`. So Typescript will return a union with all possible values for the `STEP_1_RESULT` object when called with the members of the `keyof T` union.

In our example, it will return `"title" | "label" | never | never | never`.

But since the `never` types are meaningless inside a union type, those values are discarded and we are left with `"title" | "label"`.

[image]

Comment: Nice idea. Doesn't look hacky to me, just verbose.

Comment: @CertainPerformance , thanks. You're right. Now that I've studied in more details of how it works, it's feels less weird to me. I guess I'm just not used to see this pattern.

Comment: You can also create the type in one step. In case you run out of type names to give.
type ExtractStringPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never
}[keyof T];

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure about the conditional types. What I would probably try to use here is the [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) and I would do something like

```
interface SOME_OBJECT {
    title:      string,
    label:      string,
    someBool:   boolean,
    someDate:   Date,
    someNumber: number
}

type ExtractString = Pick<SOME_OBJECT, "title" | "label">;

type STRING_KEYS = ExtractString
```

Comment: Thanks, Georgios. Your answer works for this specific example. But I need a generic way of doing it. One that should work for any object that might appear with any amount of properties and property names.